# ¿Como puedo obtener los valores del sistema, en mi caso los valores del teclado, en un idioma especifico?

Tags: java, java-swing, keypressevent, keyboard

Estoy usando un  `KeyListener` , para obtener los valores de las teclas que son apretadas, específicamente el método  `KeyEvent.getKeyText()` , pero el problema es que me devuelve el nombre/valor de las letras en español, y necesito que me devuelva siempre el valor en inglés, en lo posible, sin tener que cambiar el idioma de mi computadora o donde se esté usando el programa.
Quiero me devuelva el texto/nombre de la letra, porque luego lo muestro en pantalla, por lo tanto no puedo usar el código ASCII de las letras.

Probe usando el método  `Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH)`  pero aun así me lo sigue mostrando en español, tambien vi que los componentes de java traen un metodo `setLocale()` asi que probe poniéndoselo a el componente en el cual uso el `KeyListener` pero sigue sin funcionar.

Estoy usando el JDK 17.

Asi se ven las letras:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(Como se ve, están en español)

Adjunto la clase del componente:

```java
public class Tecla extends ComponenteBase {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private final int keyCode;

   public Tecla(int x, int y, int lapsoDeTiempo, final int keycode) {
       super(lapsoDeTiempo, tipoComponente.TECLADO);

       setLocation(x, y);

       keyCode = keycode;

       ajustarComponenteEnBaseAlTamañoDelNombre(KeyEvent.getKeyText(keycode));

       iniciarEventos();

   }


   @Override
   public void iniciarEventos() {
       activarEventosBase();
       new Eventos();
   }

   @Override
   public void ejecutar() {
       MouseClicker.ROBOT.keyPress(keyCode);
   }

   private void ajustarComponenteEnBaseAlTamañoDelNombre(final String nombre) {

       if (nombre.length() >= 5) {

           setIcon(new ImageIcon(Tecla.class.getResource("/teclarectangular.png")));
           setSize(85, 44);

           xubicacionid = 69;
           yubicacionid = 44;

           CERRAR.setLocation(72, 0);

           final JLabel primeraLinea = new JLabel(nombre, SwingConstants.CENTER);
           primeraLinea.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
           primeraLinea.setFont(new Font("arial black", 0, 10));
           add(primeraLinea);
           
           if (nombre.length() < 10) {

               primeraLinea.setBounds(8,7, 57, 25);
               
           } else {

               String oracion = sacarArticulos(nombre);
               
               if(oracion.contains("Teclado")) {
                   
                   oracion = oracion.replace("Teclado Numérico", "");
                   System.out.println(oracion);
                   oracion = "Numpad:        " + oracion;
                       
               }
               
               int indexPrimerPalabra = oracion.indexOf(" ");
               
               primeraLinea.setBounds(11, 7, 50, 14);
               primeraLinea.setText(oracion.substring(0, indexPrimerPalabra));

               final JLabel segundaLinea = new JLabel();
               segundaLinea.setBounds(11, 19, 50, 14);
               segundaLinea.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
               segundaLinea.setFont(new Font("arial black", 0, 10));
               segundaLinea.setText(oracion.substring(indexPrimerPalabra + 1, oracion.length()));
               add(segundaLinea);
           
           }

       } else {

           setIcon(new ImageIcon(Tecla.class.getResource("/tecla.png")));
           setSize(54, 50);

           final JLabel palabra = new JLabel(nombre, SwingConstants.CENTER);
           palabra.setBounds(9, 9, 24, 26);
           palabra.setFont(new Font("arial black", 0, 12));
           palabra.setText(nombre);
           palabra.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
           add(palabra);

           xubicacionid = 37;
           yubicacionid = 50;

           CERRAR.setLocation(40, 0);

       }

   }

   private String sacarArticulos(final String nombre) {

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

       for (String palabra : nombre.split(" ")) {

           if (palabra.length() > 3) {

               sb.append(palabra + " ");

           }

       }
       return sb.toString();
   }

   private final class Eventos {

       public Eventos() {

           ponerMovimiento(Tecla.this);
           actualizarElCursorAlMover();

       }

       private void actualizarElCursorAlMover() {

           addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

               @Override
               public void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent e) {

                   setCursor(null);
                   MouseClicker.LAMINA_CMPDELMOUSE.setCursor(null);

               }

           });

       }

   }

}
```

Este es el componente que tiene el KeyListener:

```java
public final class ContenedorCmpDelMouse extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final Grabador GESTOR_DE_COMPONENTESLAMINA = new Grabador();
    private final LinkedList<ComponenteBase> PUNTOS_ACTUALES_EN_CONTENEDOR = new LinkedList<>();

    public ContenedorCmpDelMouse() {

        setUndecorated(true);
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        setType(Window.Type.UTILITY);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocale(new Locale("en", "US"));
        getContentPane().setLocale(new Locale("en", "US"));
        iniciarEventos();
        getInputContext().selectInputMethod(getLocale());
        getInputContext().setCompositionEnabled(true);
        repaint();
        
    }

    private void iniciarEventos() {
        new Eventos();
    }

    public final void sePuedeClickear(final boolean clickable) {

        if (clickable) {

            setVisible(true);
            setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 1));

            GESTOR_DE_COMPONENTESLAMINA.setVisiblePuntos(MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getTogglePuntos().isSelected());

            MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.setVisible(true);

        } else {

            setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

            GESTOR_DE_COMPONENTESLAMINA.actualizarFlechas();

        }

    }

    public final boolean siClickeable() {
        return getBackground().getRGB() == new Color(0, 0, 0, 1).getRGB();
    }

    public final void vaciarLaminaPuntos() {

        final Component CMPDELMOUSE[] = getContentPane().getComponents();

        for (int i = CMPDELMOUSE.length - 1; i >= 2; i--) {

            remove(CMPDELMOUSE[i]);

        }

        GESTOR_DE_COMPONENTESLAMINA.vaciarHistorialDePuntos();

        repaint();

    }

    public final void finalizar() {

        vaciarLaminaPuntos();

        Grabador.pSeleccionado = null;

        Grabador.ComponentesGestionados = new LinkedList<>();

        sePuedeClickear(false);
        setVisible(false);

    }

    public final void ponerPuntosEnPantalla(final Preset p) {

        boolean siSeVacioLaLamina = false;

        if (!PUNTOS_ACTUALES_EN_CONTENEDOR.isEmpty() && (p.getCmpDelMouse().isEmpty()
                || !p.getCmpDelMouse().get(0).equals(PUNTOS_ACTUALES_EN_CONTENEDOR.get(0)))) {

            vaciarLaminaPuntos();
            siSeVacioLaLamina = true;

        }

        if (!p.getCmpDelMouse().isEmpty() && siSeVacioLaLamina
                || !p.getCmpDelMouse().isEmpty() && !siSeVacioLaLamina && PUNTOS_ACTUALES_EN_CONTENEDOR.isEmpty()) {

            p.getCmpDelMouse().forEach((ComponenteBase t) -> {

                t.iniciarEventos();
                anadirCmpMouse(t);

            });

        }
        repaint();

    }

    public final boolean siHayCmpsDelMouseEnContenedor() {
        return !PUNTOS_ACTUALES_EN_CONTENEDOR.isEmpty();
    }

    public final boolean siHayCmpDelMouseSinPreset() {
        return Grabador.pSeleccionado == null && !PUNTOS_ACTUALES_EN_CONTENEDOR.isEmpty();
    }

    public final Grabador getGESTOR_DE_COMPONENTESCONTENEDOR() {
        return GESTOR_DE_COMPONENTESLAMINA;
    }

    public final void registrarYAnadirNuevoComponente(final ComponenteBase nuevo) {

        GESTOR_DE_COMPONENTESLAMINA.registrarAccionCreado(nuevo);
        anadirCmpMouse(nuevo);

    }

    private void anadirCmpMouse(final ComponenteBase nuevo) {

        PUNTOS_ACTUALES_EN_CONTENEDOR.add(nuevo);

        add(nuevo);
        repaint();

        FLOTANTE.getCONTADOR_DE_COMPONENTES().setText(PUNTOS_ACTUALES_EN_CONTENEDOR.size() + "");

    }

    @Override
    public void remove(final Component cp) {
        super.remove(cp);

        if (ComponenteBase.class.isAssignableFrom(cp.getClass())) {

            Grabador.ComponentesGestionados.remove(cp);
            PUNTOS_ACTUALES_EN_CONTENEDOR.remove(cp);

            if (PUNTOS_ACTUALES_EN_CONTENEDOR.isEmpty() && FLOTANTE.getGRABAR().isEnabled()) {

                FLOTANTE.getEJECUTAR().setEnabled(false);

            }

            FLOTANTE.getCONTADOR_DE_COMPONENTES().setText(PUNTOS_ACTUALES_EN_CONTENEDOR.size() + "");

        }

    }

    private final class Eventos {

        private Timer tiempoRegresivo;
        private int cantidadDeRotacionesEnUnTiempo = 0;

        public Eventos() {
            
            accionCrearCmpMouseDondeElCursor();
            accionCrearCmpTeclado();            
            atajosDelTeclado();
        
        }

        private void accionCrearCmpMouseDondeElCursor() {

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {

                    if (!MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getGRABAR().isEnabled()) { // Esta puesto para evitar ciertos bugs

                        final Click NUEVO;

                        if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {

                            NUEVO = new ClickDerecho(e.getXOnScreen() - 15, e.getYOnScreen() - 20, obtenerDelay());

                        } else {

                            NUEVO = new ClickIzquierdo(e.getXOnScreen() - 15, e.getYOnScreen() - 20, obtenerDelay());

                        }

                        registrarYAnadirNuevoComponente(NUEVO);

                    }

                }

            });
            addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {

                @Override
                public void mouseWheelMoved(final MouseWheelEvent e) {

                    if (!MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getCOMBOBOX().getMENU().isShowing() && siNoHayUnCmpDondeEstaElCursor()
                            && cantidadDeRotacionesEnUnTiempo == 0) {

                        cantidadDeRotacionesEnUnTiempo++;
                        iniciarCuentaRegresiva();

                        final Rueda AGREGAR;

                        if (e.getWheelRotation() < 0) {

                            AGREGAR = new DesplazamientoArriba(e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen(), obtenerDelay());

                        } else {

                            AGREGAR = new DesplazamientolAbajo(e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen(), obtenerDelay());

                        }

                        registrarYAnadirNuevoComponente(AGREGAR);

                    }

                }

            });

        }
        
        private void accionCrearCmpTeclado() {
            
            addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                
                    registrarYAnadirNuevoComponente(new Tecla(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x,MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y,obtenerDelay(),e.getKeyCode()));
                    
                }
                
            });
            
        }
        
        private void atajosDelTeclado() {
            
            addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent e) {

                    AWTKeyStroke ak = AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStrokeForEvent(e);

                    if (ak.equals(AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK))) { // ctrl+z

                        GESTOR_DE_COMPONENTESLAMINA.retroceder();

                    } else if (ak.equals(AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Y, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK))) { // ctrl+y
                                                                                                                    // para
                        GESTOR_DE_COMPONENTESLAMINA.avanzar();

                    } else {

                        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {

                        case KeyEvent.VK_HOME:
                            MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getGRABAR().doClick();
                            break;

                        case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, KeyEvent.VK_INSERT, KeyEvent.VK_PAUSE:

                            if (MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getPAUSA().isEnabled()) { // Revisar

                                MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getPAUSA().doClick();

                            } else {

                                MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getEJECUTAR().doClick();

                            }

                            break;

                        case KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_UP, KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE:
                            MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getDETENER().doClick();
                            break;

                        }

                    }
                
                    
                }

            });

        }

        private int obtenerDelay() {
            return Math.abs(MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getTEMPORIZADOR().getTiempoEnMilisegundos()
                    - (PUNTOS_ACTUALES_EN_CONTENEDOR.isEmpty() ? 0
                            : PUNTOS_ACTUALES_EN_CONTENEDOR.getLast().getLapsoDeTiempo()));
        }

        private boolean siNoHayUnCmpDondeEstaElCursor() {
            return JPanel.class.isAssignableFrom(
                    getContentPane().getComponentAt(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()).getClass());
        }

        private void iniciarCuentaRegresiva() {

            try {

                if (tiempoRegresivo.alive()) {

                    tiempoRegresivo.kill();

                }

            } catch (final NullPointerException e) {

            }

            tiempoRegresivo = new Timer(0, 0, 1, new Consumer<Object>() {

            tiempoRegresivo.init();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hola, ese método, no se usa así, te pide de parámetro 2 Strings, y lo que tú le pasas son 2 variables de tipo Locale, desde ya mUchas gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Intenta con
InputContext context = InputContext.getInstance();  
System.out.println(context.getLocale().toString());

Comment: También puedes cambiarlo desde el mismo componente: `TuComponente.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(new Locale("en", "US"));`

Comment: Sal, intente lo que me dijiste. Haciendo eso vi que me cambio la configuración del idioma del teclado, a ingles en la computadora, pero aun así me sigue devolviendo el nombre de la tecla en español.   También probe usando otras funciones de ese método pero sin resultados.

Comment: Rusian Lopez, probe haciendolo asi pero el metodo context.getLocale().toString() solo me devuleve el idioma establecido.

Comment: si le quitas el toString te da el locale :v

Comment: jjajajja pero si nesecito el nombre de la tecla :V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe un [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6292739) ya reportado anteriormente al respecto.

### Como cambiar los nombres de los aceleradores de teclas

Afortunadamente se peude cambiar el locale justo al momento que inicia la aplicacion, con la limitante de que despues no podras cambiarlo.

Para ello agrega el parametro

```
-Duser.language=
```

Y luego las dos letras que usas normalmente en tu locale, por ejemplo ES, DE, FR, etc

por ejemplo en mi caso para lanzar la aplicacion en italiano

```
java -Duser.language=IT -jar respuestasstackoverflow-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

[image: locale cambiado de los aceleradores de teclas]

Si a alguien le interesa el codigo de la palicacion es este:

```
package com.github.javatlacati.respuestasstackoverflow.questions554869;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class TeclasTest extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form TeclasTest
     */
    public TeclasTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        lblNombreTecla = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                formKeyReleased(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(49, 49, 49)
                .addComponent(lblNombreTecla, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 212, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(139, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(127, 127, 127)
                .addComponent(lblNombreTecla, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 93, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(80, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void formKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 
        lblNombreTecla.setText(KeyEvent.getKeyText(evt.getKeyCode()));
    }                                

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TeclasTest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TeclasTest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TeclasTest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TeclasTest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TeclasTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblNombreTecla;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

### Como se origina el bug

Resulta que KeyEvent para traer la descripcion manda llamar a Toolkit

```
Toolkit.getProperty("AWT.enter", "Enter");
```

Y Toolkit se inicializa cargando un archivo privado de propiedades

```
resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("sun.awt.resources.awt");
```

dicho archivo esta localizado y presente [en tu JDK](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/tree/master/src/share/classes/sun/awt/resources).

esta llamada se realiza una sola vez cuando inicializa tu maquina virtual eligiendo la version que detecta del sistema operativo y desde alli no hay ningun metodo para cambiarlo cuando se cambia el locale.

Comment: Muchas gracias! 
Me funciono, aunque es molesto que haya que hacer eso para arreglarlo, pero bueno, son cosas de java.